# clusterSettings is not a member of com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.Builder

Tags: mongodb, scala, sbt

I'm trying to use mongodb client from scala. I use IntelliJ IDEA.

In this line:

```
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
                                             .builder()
                                             .clusterSettings(clusterSettings)
                                             .build()
```

I get error:

> clusterSettings is not a member of com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.Builder

Though dependencies and imports seem to be correct.

Here is sbt file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-core" % "3.7.0"
```

And here are includes:

```
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClientSettings
import org.mongodb.scala.connection.ClusterSettings
```

It seems that nobody has this problem out in the internet, but my colleague had the same issue recently. Any ideas what is the problem here?

**UPDATE:**

As per comment from Ross i've modified sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.3.0"
```

And modified code:

```
import com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClientSettings

val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
  .builder()
  .applyToClusterSettings((b: ClusterSettings.Builder) => b.applySettings(clusterSettings))
  .build()
```

Now IDEA does not complain and it sees all API, but during compilation i get error:

> Error:(9, 60) type mismatch;
>    found   : com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.Builder => com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.Builder
>    required: com.mongodb.Block[com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.Builder]
>         .applyToClusterSettings((b: ClusterSettings.Builder) => b.applySettings(clusterSettings))

But if I define block outside and then use it - it compiles successfully:

```
 val block: Block[ClusterSettings.Builder] = new Block[ClusterSettings.Builder] {
  override def apply(t: ClusterSettings.Builder): Unit = {
    t.applySettings(clusterSettings)
  }
}

val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
  .builder()
  .applyToClusterSettings(block)
  .build()
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Note there is no need to add a `mongodb-driver-core` dependency its already set via the `mongo-scala-driver`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a change to the type alias in 2.3.0 for `MongoClientSettings` and that has a slightly different API to the previous builder. See the upgrade guide: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.3/upgrade/#mongoclientsettings

The reason it was changed is because the `com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientSettings` was deprecated in favour of a new centralised `MongoClientSettings`.

You can still use the deprecated settings for now. Update (refresh) your sbt project and intellij will highlight the lack of a `clusterSettings` method on the builder.

An example of applying settings to the new `MongoClientSettings`:

```
import com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings

// Scala 2.12 (support for Single Abstract Methods)
val clientSettings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
      .builder()
      .applyToClusterSettings((b: ClusterSettings.Builder) => b.applySettings(clusterSettings))
      .build()

// Scala 2.11 you must provide the block:
val clientSettings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
      .builder()
      .applyToClusterSettings(new Block[ClusterSettings.Builder]() {
        override def apply(b: ClusterSettings.Builder): Unit = b.applySettings(clusterSettings)
      })
      .build()
```

Comment: thank you. That almost solved the problem - please see an update.

Comment: Updated, Scala 2.11 doesn't support the SAM syntax posted, updated the example

Comment: Thank you, the official documentation doesn't explain this odd syntax